# XenServer 6.5 Software Raid

Tags: software-raid, xenserver

I try to install XenServer 6.5 with Software-RAID 1 at my home lab.
With XenServer 6.2 this setup ran stable for a few months (at the same hardware).

XenServer 6.5 installation went smoothly and boots up without any errors.
After enabling the kernel module with

```
echo "modprobe raid1" > /etc/sysconfig/modules/raid.modules
```

I followed [this guide](https://blog.trendelkamp.net/2015/02/configure-software-raid-xenserver-6-5/). Everything went fine until I have to boot from sdb.
I can see the XenServer logo (without the loading bar) for a few seconds, then the server screen goes black and a reboot happen.

Does anybody know what went wrong or what I can try to fix the problem?

Comment: Can you type ESC to see more information at boot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem. The guide is wrong.
It is extremely important to create the `mdadm.conf` before running `mkinitrd`.
Without the correct mdadm.conf the device mapper will name /dev/md0 to something silly (/dev/md125). The problem then is, that the device for the rootfs is not found at boot.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use e2label on md0 (RAID on first partitions) to add label on filesystem and make booting process independendent from /dev/md* names.